# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#fd8d7 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter

I've specified the Height and still, it's throwing errors, kindly don't suggest other questions on StackOverflow I've already tried but have not found any solutionn, kindly help help me

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: isListening ? Colors.black87 : Colors.black54,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
             const SizedBox(height: 12),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 12),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: chatBg,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: messages. Length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var chat = messages[index];
                    return chatBubble(chattext: chat. Text, type: chat. Type);
                  },
                ),
              )),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because `Column` is inside `Scrollable` view. And you are using `Expanded` as a child of `Column`.

Now the problem is flutter compiler gets confused how much to expand the `Expanded` widget. Because there is no constraint on the length of the `Column`(parent Widget) as it is scrollable, and possibly be expanded to infinite length, Which can't be done, so this error.

Try removing `Expanded` and give it desired height of your choice.

---

Your Current Structure:

```
SingleChildScrollView
 |_Container
   |_Column
     |_Expanded
       |_ ListView
```

Change it to

```
SingleChildScrollView
 |_Container
   |_Column
      |_ ListView
```